# Hard drive swap problems

Tags: hard-drive, high-definition

I have two old computers. I'm trying to put the hard drive from an old Acer into an old Hp.  The problem I ran into is little plastic tangs that prevent the hard drive pins from being able to be inserted into the HP. It looks like both drives have the same number of pins? The computers are both of the same vintage. I tried to attached several pics to help, but a message told me I can't do that?

Comment: This is in two old laptops.  The drive I am trying to put into the other laptop drive bay appears that it would fit fine if the little plastic tangs were not  there?

Comment: Are you able to put the pics somewhere else and link to yjem? Its difficult to envision what you are saying, and hard drives are pretty standardised so tjis should be possible.  Is one (or both) hard drive maybe in a thin holder?

Comment: I have a google account, but not sure how to send the files for you to access?

Comment: Here try this link.  https://www.dropbox.com/t/DxB8JWYInl4mFLRT

Comment: It seems the drive has a proprietary adapter. Remove it.

Comment: Agree with @ChanganAuto - the last dropbox pic shows a non-standard connector on what looks like an otherwise standard drive.  It probably just pulls off.

Comment: let me go look and see if I can pull it off.....

Comment: Sure enough.. It came right off.  I didn't see the connector on there!  Thank you both SO MUCK.  It connected perfectly.